# Is there more elegant way for this type of permutations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, permutation

I have this code:

```
import itertools
variations = list(itertools.permutations(['a', 'b', 'c'], 2))
for v in variations:
    print(''.join(v))
```

I want all characters. If I want use this code I should write something like this:

```
variations = list(itertools.permutations(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', '.......
```

Isn't there a more elegant way?

Comment: Why the additional `list()`?

Comment: `['a', 'b', 'c']` and `'abc'` doesn't make different outputs here.

Comment: Converting to a list is absolutely unnecessary, in fact if there's a large number of items it will increase the resource usage drastically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use a string instead of a list of strings. Additionally, you can use the `string` module and use the predefined constant [`ascii_lowercase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase) for all lowercase letters:

```
import string
variations = itertools.permutations(string.ascii_lowercase, 2)
```

If you want additional characters you can just grow the string to include the characters you want or you can use one of the other [string constants](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string-constants) defined in the string module:

```
...permutations(string.ascii_lowercase + '/\\$!@#%', 2)
...permutations(string.printable, 2)
```

Comment: `string.printable` is what you need